# o1566.showString error persists even with os env variables defined with PySpark in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis, pyspark-schema

I am a beginner at using PySpark and since I do not have access to the databricks platform, I am currently exploring learning through JupyterNotebook. I have reviewed other forums and tried different methods, however, the problem still persists when I run the .show() method. Below is my code:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import os
import sys

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("AnotherTestDemo").getOrCreate()

import json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, ArrayType, LongType, IntegerType, DateType

myschema = StructType([
    StructField("EmpID", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("Details", StructType([
        StructField("FirstName", StringType(), True),
        StructField("LastName", StringType(), True),
        StructField("ADEmail", StringType(), True),
        StructField("DOB", StringType(), True),
        StructField("State", StringType(), True),
        StructField("GenderCode", StringType(), True),
        StructField("LocationCode", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("RaceDesc", StringType(), True),
        StructField("MaritalDesc", StringType(), True),
    ]), True),
    StructField("JobProfile", StructType([
        StructField("Title", StringType(), True),
        StructField("BusinessUnit", StringType(), True),
        StructField("Supervisor", StringType(), True),
        StructField("EmployeeType", StringType(), True),
        StructField("DepartmentType", StringType(), True),
        StructField("Division", StringType(), True),
        StructField("JobFunctionDescription", StringType(), True),
    ]), True),
    StructField("Payroll", StructType([
        StructField("EmployeeClassificationType", StringType(), True),
        StructField("PayZone", StringType(), True),
    ]), True),
    StructField("Performance", StructType([
        StructField("Performance Score", StringType(), True),
        StructField("Current Employee Rating", IntegerType(), True),
    ]), True),
    StructField("History", StructType([
        StructField("StartDate", DateType(), True),
        StructField("EmployeeStatus", StringType(), True),
        StructField("ExitDetails", ArrayType(StructType([
            StructField("ExitDate", DateType(), True),
            StructField("TerminationType", StringType(), True),
            StructField("TerminationDescription", StringType(), True),
        ])), True),
    ]), True)
])
schemadefined_df = spark.read.json("employee_data.json", schema=myschema, multiLine=True)

from pysparketl.dataframes import flattenDF
with_defined_schema_df = flattenDF(schemadefined_df)

with_defined_schema_df.show()
```

The specific error message is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-b38a28ad0f7b> in <module>
      1 #with_defined_schema_df.show()

C:\Spark\spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    897 
    898         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 899             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    900         else:
    901             try:

C:\Spark\spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1320 
   1321         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322         return_value = get_return_value(
   1323             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 

C:\Spark\spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    167     def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    168         try:
--> 169             return f(*a, **kw)
    170         except Py4JJavaError as e:
    171             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

C:\Spark\spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1573.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 87.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 87.0 (TID 60) (LAPTOP-KQHH2FNK executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.GenericArrayData cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Integer
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow.getInt(rows.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow.getInt$(rows.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericInternalRow.getInt(rows.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.writeFields_1_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.$anonfun$apply$1(FileFormat.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.next(FileScanRDD.scala:211)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:888)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:888)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2785)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2721)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2984)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2923)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2912)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:971)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2263)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2284)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2303)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:530)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:483)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:4177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:3161)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:4167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:526)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:4165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:4165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:3161)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:3382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:323)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.GenericArrayData cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Integer
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow.getInt(rows.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow.getInt$(rows.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericInternalRow.getInt(rows.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.writeFields_1_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.$anonfun$apply$1(FileFormat.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.next(FileScanRDD.scala:211)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:888)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:888)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    ... 1 more
```

Further details:
PySpark version: 3.4.1
Python version: 3.8.8
I have also restarted the Jupyter kernel and still the same error when running the .show() function

Comment: Don't provide the schema for the first go. Read in the dataframe as it is.  Then print out 

`print(dataframe.schema)`  and see if there is mismatch between your provided schema and the printed schema. That's what the error is pointing out.

Comment: @user238607 Okay I understand what you're saying, since for example EmpID was originally of type long but since I defined a new schema with EmpID having a datatype of INT instead of long, why does it throw an error? Should it not automatically use the new schema or is there some type of casting to be done?

Comment: It's not a long. It seems it is an array according to the error. 

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.GenericArrayData cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Integer
`

Comment: @user238607 According to the original schema (not the one I posted), the datatype of EmpID is set to long. Maybe it has something to do with whoever initially created the dataset. Nonetheless, thank you so much for helping me understand where I was going wrong, much appreciated.